# How to read in file with delimiter in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, fixed-width

I am using the pandas library and how can I split the given dataframe into rows and columns based on comma seprated.
  Because if I try it gives the error it cannot seprate and throws following error.

```
6.1101,17.592
5.5277,9.1302
8.5186,13.662
7.0032,11.854
5.8598,6.8233
8.3829,11.886
```

And the above given line consist my dataset.
 And the code is:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dataframe = pd.read_fwf("challenge_dataset.txt")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pandas.read_fwf` can have delimiter argument.

```
dataframe = pd.read_fwf("challenge_dataset.txt", delimiter=",")
```

You can read more in [pandas.read_fwf](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html)

[read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) is automatically reads with comma separator, although you can change the delimiter argument in `read_csv` as well.

Comment: How can I seprate the data such that the first corresponds to x value of graph and second to the y value?

Comment: Note that pandas read_fwf is for fixed width format, which the OP is not showing. This answer works but read_csv is more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

You need read_csv for comma separated values:

```
rt pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.read_csv("challenge_dataset.txt")
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html